# Facebook: extracting user information from access token

Tags: facebook, json, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

i used the user's valid access token to identify the user...

with this:
`https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id&access_token=VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN`

it returns:

```
{
   "id": "100000004811603"
}
```

it's obvious that i only want to extract the user's id... that's the only one thing i need to do everything for the user/

can someone teach me how to parse this?
it's weird for me seeing this type of result without the `Data:` key

Comment: Which language is using for this(java,php,android,etc)?

Comment: Could you post your code snippet? the sample code with the SDK shows how to do this, so i'm not sure what you're doing that makes this difficult

Comment: i'm not using any kind of facebook sdks.... i just parse them with jsondecode.... but i only know how to parse jsons with "data:" but in this case... i dont know how... this is my first encounter with this ...

Comment: @IvanIvanić sorry...but i dont use them anymore... they're just an addition to the loading time...

Comment: Php sdk can't be addition to loading time if you mean browser loading time. Functions in php sdk are well written and do same thing that you are trying to do. For js sdk your statement is true.

Comment: @IvanIvanić my server is having trouble with facebook CA's. i'm using only free web hosting server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on how you described your problem I'll try to answer.

```
$response = // get facebook response as you do
$data = json_decode($response);
$id_that_you_need = $data['id']
```

Maybe I'm getting you all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

```
function objectToArray( $object )
{
    if( !is_object( $object ) && !is_array( $object ) )
    {
        return $object;
    }
    if( is_object( $object ) )
    {
        $object = get_object_vars( $object );
    }
    return array_map( 'objectToArray', $object );
}
```

pass the output from https://graph.facebook.com/me? to this function. this function will return array. and you can use values easily.

like this

$Array = objectToArray($Data);

print_r($Array);

Comment: how you are getting output from https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id&access_token=VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN

show me the code

Answer (score 0):

```
$facebook_token = <VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN>;
$user_information = curl_init("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=$facebook_token");
curl_setopt($user_information,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,FALSE);
curl_setopt($user_information,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,FALSE);
curl_setopt($user_information,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$reps= curl_exec($user_information);
curl_close($user_information);
echo($reps);`
```

`